# Unused inherited member and method

Tags: c#, inheritance

Hi guys :) I am learning C# and would like some help about inherited member/field. I have a class called Car, suppose with only one engine. However, recently I want to make a race car with 2 or more engines. The field "my_Engine" inherited from parent class seems not appropriate and I leave it to null.

Problem 1 Replace_Engine(Engine new_Engine) no longer usable in Race_Car

Problem 2 Replace_Engine(Engine target, Engine new_Engine) can only be used after an explicit cast to Race_Car.

I have quite a number of subclass of Car. How can I solve these? Do I need to rewrite all of them?

Should I rewrite them all, does replacing my_Engine to an array good enough? But not all cars have more than 1 engine... using an array seems strange. I am quite confused here.

Appreciated all your help :)

```
public class Car 
{
    //can store only one engine
    protected Engine my_Engine;

    //Changed to virtual to let Race_Car to override
    public virtual float Get_Horse_Power()
    {
        return my_Engine.max_Power;
    }

    //Changed to virtual to let Race_Car to override
    public virtual void Replace_Engine(Engine new_Engine)
    {
        my_Engine = new_Engine;
    }
}

public class Race_Car : Car
{
    protected Engine[] my_Engines;

    public override float Get_Horse_Power()
    {
        float result=0;
        for(int i = 0; i <my_Engines.Length;i++)
        {
            result+=my_Engines.max_Power;
        }
        return result;
    }

    //Don't know which engine need to be replaced
    public override void Replace_Engine(Engine new_Engine)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    //Created a overloading method but need an explicit cast to call
    public void Replace_Engine(Engine target, Engine new_Engine)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i <my_Engines.Length;i++)
        {
            if(my_Engines[i]==target)
            {
                my_Engines[i]= new_Engine;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could leave it "as is" and make a new engine that is composed of two or more engines. Like a processor having multiple cores, but it is still a single processor.

Comment: C# is not Python, don't use underscore in classes and methods names. `Race_Car` should be `RaceCar`, `Get_Horse_Power()` should be `GetHorsePower()` etc.

Comment: Seems like you broke your design by inroducing a car that has more than one engine. You may add a further abstraction, e.g. a `DefaultCar` having a single engine. While the most cars now inherit from `DefaultCar`, you have another class with two ingines: `SuperCar` that directly derives from `BaseCar`. `BaseClass` therefor doesn´t need an engine at all.

Comment: Hi @Kevin, welcome to SO. Will the car have exactly two engines? Or any number of engines?

Comment: @JuanR any number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base class here assumes *in the API* that there is only a single engine, so yes: this will be awkward to use with types that don't adhere to that API. You could perhaps do something like:

```
public virtual int EngineCount => 1;
public virtual void ReplaceEngine(Engine newEngine, int engineIndex = 0)
{
    if(engineIndex != 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(engineIndex));
    _engine = newEngine;
}
```

and:

```
public override int EngineCount => 2;
public void override ReplaceEngine(Engine newEngine, int engineIndex = 0)
{
    switch(engineIndex)
    {
        case 1: _secondEngine = newEngine; break;
        default: base.ReplaceEngine(newEngine, engineIndex); break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Does that mean I am wrong to assume that a car has only a single engine? Should I declare everything as array in order to safe guard against the future possible changes like FuelTank[] instead of FuelTank?

Comment: @KevinSin "However, recently I want to make a race car with 2 or more engines." - so... yes, you're wrong to assume that a car has one engine; personally I would not advise using arrays here without good reason, unless it is likely that you genuinely need to support arbitrary numbers of {whatever}

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to go about this is to make the concept of an `Engine` abstract and let the fact that you may have more than one physical unit serving the power be of no consequence to the original design.

You start with an abstract class that represents an engine:

```
public abstract class Engine
{
    public Engine()
    {

    }
    internal abstract float max_Power { get; }
}
```

You then implement the two flavors of engines. A simple one:

```
public class SimpleEngine : Engine
{
    private float _maxPower;

    public SimpleEngine(float maxPower)
    {
        _maxPower = maxPower;
    }


    internal override float MaxPower
    {
        get { return _maxPower; }            
    }
}
```

And a composite one:

```
public class CompositeEngine : Engine
{
    private List<Engine> _engines = new List<Engine>();

    public CompositeEngine(params Engine[] engines)
    {
        _engines.AddRange(engines);
    }

    internal override float MaxPower
    {
        get { return _engines.Sum(e => e.MaxPower); }             
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var engine = new CompositeEngine(new SimpleEngine(5), new SimpleEngine(4), new SimpleEngine(3));
var car = new Car();
car.Replace_Engine(engine);            
var value = car.Get_Horse_Power();
```

Output:

> value = 12

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried both Marc Gravell♦ and your solution. And both your answer could solve. In your abstract Engine class, I added 2 methods. 
Replace(Engine newEngine) and 
Replace(Engine oldEngine, Engine newEngine) 
to avoid the need of casting to CompositeEngine. Or should I put the 2nd method in CompositeEngine which requies a casting?

Comment: @KevinSin: It sounds like the second method belongs to the composite engine. I am not sure why you think it requires casting. They should all inherit from Engine so you should just be able to pass it along as a parameter.

Comment: @KevinSin: By the way, the first method belongs in your `Car` class. Think about these things as real life objects. Methods are stuff these things can do. Your car needs the first method because it makes sense that you should be able to switch the car's engine. In the case of the composite engine, you want to be able to switch the physical units that comprise the "mega engine".